# Bounds for PDF of Sum of Two Dependent Random Variables

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables

Assume $X$ and $Y$ are two dependent random variables and we do not have the joint distribution of these two. Is there an upper/lower bound for the PDF of $X+Y$? I found a paper which provides bounds but it needs additional random variable $Z$ with known distribution as a function of $X$ and $Y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general there is no lower bound other than $0$, and no upper bound.  Worse,  $X+Y$ might not even have a PDF, it might be discrete (e.g. try $Y = -X$).